# Moving through the Recordset in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I have a simple function using Excel VBA for calculating volatility. It takes as inputs a column of numbers (Zeros) and two dates. The code is:

```
Function EWMA(Zeros As Range, Lambda As Double, MarkDate As Date, MaturityDate As Date) As Double

    Dim vZeros() As Variant
    Dim Price1 As Double, Price2 As Double
    Dim SumWtdRtn As Double
    Dim I As Long
    Dim m As Double

    Dim LogRtn As Double, RtnSQ As Double, WT As Double, WtdRtn As Double

vZeros = Zeros

m = Month(MaturityDate) - Month(MarkDate)

For I = 2 To UBound(vZeros, 1)

    Price1 = Exp(-vZeros(I - 1, 1) * (m / 12))

    Price2 = Exp(-vZeros(I, 1) * (m / 12))

    LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)

    RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2

    WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)

    WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ

    SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn

Next I

EWMA = SumWtdRtn ^ (1 / 2)

End Function
```

The main feature enabling the function to work is the For loop.  I want to re-create this in Access VBA using recordset objects. The recordset has the same fields as the Excel spreadsheet. I'm not exactly sure how to convert the code over, though. Here is what I have so far:

```
Function EWMA(rsCurve As Recordset, InterpRate As Double, Lambda As Double) As Double

    Dim vZeros() As Variant
    Dim Price1 As Double, Price2 As Double
    Dim SumWtdRtn As Double
    Dim I As Long
    Dim mat As Date
    Dim mark As Date

    Dim LogRtn As Double, RtnSQ As Double, WT As Double, WtdRtn As Double


    CurveInterpolateRecordset = Rnd()

    If rsCurve.RecordCount <> 0 Then

    vZeros = CVar(rsCurve.Fields("CurveInterpolateRecordset"))

    mat = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate"))
    mark = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MarkDate"))

    m = Month(mat) - Month(mark)

For I = 2 To UBound(vZeros, 1)

    Price1 = Exp(-vZeros(I - 1, 1) * (m / 12))

    Price2 = Exp(-vZeros(I, 1) * (m / 12))

    LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)

    RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2

    WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)

    WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ

    SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn

Next I

EWMA = SumWtdRtn ^ (1 / 2)

End If

        Debug.Print EWMA

End Function
```

The function is called in an earlier subroutine in Access. What am I missing in order to move through the recordset in Access, similar to looping through the spreadsheet in Excel VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use `GetRows` to pull an array from your recordset:

[Recordset.GetRows Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221041(v=office.12).aspx)

Then the new code would be nearly a copy-n-paste of your proven code starting with basically this:

```
vZeros = rsCurve.GetRows(rsCurve.RecordCount)
```

As a side note you wouldn't need CDate here:

```
mat = rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some basics about using a recordset.

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.
With rs
    .Fields.Append "Row", adInteger
    .Fields.Append "ColumnName2", adChar, 30
    .Fields.Append "ColumnName3", adInteger
    .Open
End With
```

Add records to it manually

```
rs.AddNew
rs.Fields("Row").Value = 1
rs.Fields("ColumnName2").Value = "Put some value in"   
rs.Update

rs.AddNew
rs.Fields("Row").Value = 2
rs.Fields("ColumnName2").Value = "Put another value in"   
rs.Update
```

You can also populate it with a query of a table.

Move to the begining of the recordset

```
If rs.EOF = False Then
    rs.MoveFirst
End If
```

Loop through the recordset

```
Do While rs.EOF = False

        msgbox(rs.Fields("ColumnName2").Value)

rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you. I am confused about one point though. If I want to loop through the recordset for a specific interval [ I = 2 to UBound(vZeros,1) ], is it sufficient to just move to the beginning of the recordset and loop through?

Comment: That is just an example of general recordset navigation.  You can do just about anything you want with it.

Comment: @varunchandra: Typically you use a SELECT query for your recordset that returns **exactly the records** you want to loop through, by using an appropriate WHERE condition.