# Loop through recordset data 10 records at a time and add to array

Tags: vba, ms-access

**Context:** I am writing a Google Maps API in my Microsoft Access database which takes postcodes in a table and sends them over to Google as part of a HTTP GET request. To make my requests more efficient, I am trying to batch 10 postcodes together at a time to send over to Google. I have chosen 10 as Google has a `2000` character limit in it's GET API requests.

**Exam Question:** Using `DAO recordsets`, how do I loop through my `Postcodes` table, 10 records at a time and add those 10 records to an array, until I reach the end of the table? So in essence, get 10 records from the table, add them to an array, then clear the array, then get the next 10 records and add them to the array, then clear the array...until I reach the end of the table.

My basic code so far is:

```
Public Function CalcGeoData()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Postcodes(0 To 10) As String

    ' Begin to loop through the Postcodes in I_Postcodes and update for distance and time from base
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Postcodes")
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then

        rs.MoveFirst

        Do Until rs.EOF = True

            Debug.Print (rs!Postcode)
            Debug.Print "-----------"

            rs.Move 10

        Loop

    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop:

- Create another loop from i = 1 to 10. Inside that loop:

  - Add the values from the current record to myArray(i).
  - Special case: If the end of the recordset is reached, clear the remaining array entries.
- Send the array to Google (or do whatever else you want to do with it).

Translating this to code is left as an exercise.

Note: You might want to consider using a VBA `Collection` instead of an array, which has a useful [Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265006(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: I should have been more specific. I need to add 10 records to the array, then clear the array and add the next 10 records to the array, then clear that...and so forth...until the end. I've amended my question.

Comment: @BarryBlade: My solution still applies: resetting myArray(i) will overwrite the old value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GetRows` method: [Moving through the Recordset in Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348097/moving-through-the-recordset-in-access-vba/33356555#33356555)

Put it inside a loop where you pull 10 records (not `RecordCount` as shown) in each loop until no more records.

Comment: Within the loop how do I choose to select records 1 to 10, then 11 to 20, then 21 to 30 and so forth?

Comment: Just pull 10. The method advances itself the recordset.